# How to find out what's making svchost eat up bandwidth on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bandwidth, svchost

It's been trying to download some 2.5gb since last night and when I started up my computer now, it's doing so again. I have limited bandwidth and would like to know what is using it up.

[image]

I thought it was an update to Windows 10 but there doesn't seem to be any here.

[image]

Comment: put the mouse over the svchost.exe entry in ProcessExplorer and look which services are hosted by this svchost.exe

Comment: Yeah but I have no idea how to determine which of those services are using up the internet

Comment: but at least you have a starting point. Which services o you see listed there?

Comment: I managed to fix my issue by renaming/deleting `SoftwareDistribution` while Windows was powered down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem. I think Windows Update messed up. What I did was make a liveUSB running a distro of Linux (any should do) and boot using that, using the Linux file manager, I just renamed the folder `SoftwareDistribution` which is in `C:\Windows\` folder and rebooted back to Windows. After that, it no longer happened.